# Tex4ht/MathJax - Matrix equation with aligned rows

Tags: align, matrices, tex4ht, mathjax

By using tex4ht I'm processing a tex document with a matrix equation where I would like the rows of all different arrays to be aligned (i.e. all row should have the same thickness). The latex document looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
u_{x_{i}} \\[0.7ex]
u_{y_{i}} \\[0.7ex]
u_{z_{i}} \\[0.7ex]
\phi_{x_{i}} \\[0.7ex]
\phi_{y_{i}} \\[0.7ex]
\phi_{z_{i}}
\end{array} \right\}
=
\left[ \begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[0.7ex]
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[0.7ex]
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\[0.7ex]
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\[0.7ex]
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\[0.7ex]
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array} \right]
\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
u_{x_{i}} \\[0.7ex]
u_{y_{i}} \\[0.7ex]
u_{z_{i}} \\[0.7ex]
\phi_{x_{i}} \\[0.7ex]
\phi_{y_{i}} \\[0.7ex]
\phi_{z_{i}}
\end{array} \right\}
\end{equation}
 \end{document}
```

The final html shows the error"Unknown code type:tr" as shown in the figure below. This error appears when is use when I impose the row thickness [0.7ex] and (I think) is a limitation of MathJax. 
[image]

The corresponding html code of the equation is the following:

```
<math class="equation" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mfenced separators="" open="{" close="}">
    <mrow>
      <mtable class="array" align="axis" style="" equalrows="false" columnlines="" equalcolumns="false">
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>u</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>x</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>i</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>u</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>y</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>i</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>u</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>z</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>i</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>&#x3D5;</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>x</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>i</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>&#x3D5;</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>y</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>i</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>&#x3D5;</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>z</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>i</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
      </mtable>
    </mrow>
  </mfenced>
  <mo class="MathClass-rel">=</mo>
  <mfenced separators="" open="[" close="]">
    <mrow>
      <mtable class="array" align="axis" style="" equalrows="false" columnlines="none none none none none" equalcolumns="false">
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>1</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>1</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>1</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>1</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>1</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>0</mn>
          </mtd>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <mn>1</mn>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
      </mtable>
    </mrow>
  </mfenced>
  <mfenced separators="" open="{" close="}">
    <mrow>
      <mtable class="array" align="axis" style="" equalrows="false" columnlines="" equalcolumns="false">
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>u</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>x</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>j</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>u</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>y</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>j</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>u</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>z</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>j</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>&#x3D5;</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>x</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>j</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>&#x3D5;</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>y</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>j</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd>
            <merror>
              <mtext>Unknown node type: tr</mtext>
            </merror>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
          <mtd class="array" columnalign="center">
            <msub>
              <mrow>
                <mi>&#x3D5;</mi>
              </mrow>
              <mrow>
                <msub>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>z</mi>
                  </mrow>
                  <mrow>
                    <mi>j</mi>
                  </mrow>
                </msub>
              </mrow>
            </msub>
          </mtd>
        </mtr>
      </mtable>
    </mrow>
  </mfenced>
</math>
```

Does anyone know a way to solve/overcome this issue?

Comment: The "corresponding HTML code" is tex4ht's output, correct?

Comment: This looks like a tex4ht problem. Note that the error message is in the "corresponding HTML code" (which is actually MathML). FWIW, MathJax's TeX input would process the content `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` just fine.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I don't think the showed `HTML` is produced by `tex4ht`, unless OP heavily configured it. The default `mathml` output for the sample document doesn't contain any `merror` elements, for instance.

Comment: @michal.h21 ok. It doesn't look like a MathJax issue either.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger what is strange is that the generated `html` doesn't contain any `tr` elements and it is displayed correctly by MathJax for me. This must be some misconfiguration on the OP's side

Comment: Do you use any custom configurations? I don't get this error with `html5,mathml` options for `tex4ht`